# AJAX add data to table without resetting table.

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, partial-page-refresh

I have a php page that will grab data from an SQL database and print it into a table, now if certain rows from the database have a certain parameter, a hidden row is inserted below that with a button to expand the row. This all works fine and I can query it with ajax into a div on a different page, but if someone were to expand the hidden row (with jquery) and the ajax update timer were to come along, it would reset and hide that row.

Here is the page that it is filled into and the ajax code to go with it:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#query").load("query.php");
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $("#query").load('query.php');
   }, 5000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 

});
</script>

<div id="query"></div>
```

And from the query.php:

```php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
      $decoded = json_decode($row['B'],true);
      $r = $decoded['r'];
      $t = $decoded['t']; 
      $l = $decoded['l'];       
      $g = $decoded['g'];      
      $tp = (int)$t + 3;            

      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td align=\"center\"><font color=\"red\">[$t]</font></td>";
      echo "<td align=\"center\"><font color=\"blue\">[$r]</font></td>";
      echo(((int)$t != 0) ? '<td><button class="expand stylebutton">+</button>' : '<td>');
      echo $row['Name_'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['Date_'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['IP'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['G'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['A'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['Add'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['Remove'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['Comments'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      if((int)$t != 0)
    {
          echo "<tr class=\"b\"style=\"display: none;\">";
          echo "<td></td><td colspan=\"$tp\"><div style=\"color: #FC0;\"> Local:</div>";
          foreach($l as $ll)
          {
            echo $ll . "<br>";
          }
          echo "<br><div style=\"color: #F00;\">Global:</div>";
          foreach($g as $gg)
          {
            echo $gg . "<br> ";
          }
          echo "</td></tr>";
    }
    }
    echo "</table>";
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
echo "$(document).ready(function() {
        $(\".stylebutton\").click(function(){
            $(this).parent().parent().next().toggle();
         if($(this).text() == \"+\")
         {
            $(this).text('-');
         }
         else
         {
            $(this).text('+');
         }
        });
});
</script>";
```

[Here's an image of what one of the rows looks like when expanded.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRPXH.jpg)

So basically I don't want the rows to contract when the ajax update rolls through, but instead just add more data on to the page. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You should have the php file return the data in json format to be used by your jQuery. Instead of replacing the html tags and causing your UI to retract, you will replace the data.

**For Example**

Your php code:

```
$data_array = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
  array_push( $row['some_row'] , $data_array ); // add the data to an array that will later be json encoded
}

echo json_encode($data_array);
```

jQuery

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'query.php',
  success: function(data) {
    alert('This is the JSON: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    $('#selector').text(data.some_row); // place the data inside the element with id = 'selector'
  }
});
```

Comment: OK, but wouldn't that just keep repeating the same data over and over?Sorry I'm relativly new to ajax and jquery and the whole web development world so I could be totally wrong.

Comment: Actually, it would. What you're going to want to do is use json to replace the data, and not the html tags. Does this make sense or am I reading your question wrong?

Comment: No that makes sense, I just wouldn't know how to go about doing that.

Comment: I do this, and I get no results. Where does the JSON.stringify() get its data? And I'm guessing I replace data.some_row with something like data.ID?

Comment: check my updated code. And yes, replace with a key value from the array. This is only example code.

Comment: Ok, I got it mostly working, the alert echos back all the data, but the jquery to place it in the element returns nothing, even after changing the some_row.

Comment: Try using data['some_row'] and in the php, use json_encode($var, true).

Comment: Wait I figured it out, it should be `array_push($data_array, $row['some_id']);`

Comment: I am also able to output the data as a json encoded array, now I need to be able to put that into a table and add the hidden rows.

Comment: Could I get some help with the jquery JSON part? I can return it as json, but I need to get this into a table.

Comment: Hey Joseph, I'd say get on chat but you don't  have enough rep. Add me on msn: austinallover@hotmail.com or skype: austin-oliver